# Remove Inverted Comma from generated MYSQL in ZendFramework2

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, code-generation

I have been creating a MYSQL statement in ZF2:

```
/**
 * get response by filter
 */
public function getResponsesByFilterArray($filter_array)
{
    $limit = 100;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(
            function (\Zend\Db\Sql\Select $select) use($where, $limit, $filter_array)
            {
                //$select->quantifier('DISTINCT');
                $select->join('question_responses', 'survey_responses.id = question_responses.response_id', array('value'));
                $select->where($where);
                foreach($filter_array as $filter_model)
                {

                    $select->where(array('question_id' => $filter_model->question_id));

                    switch($filter_model->comparison){
                        case $filter_model::$EQUALS:
                            $select->where->equalTo('value', $filter_model->value);
                            break;
                        case $filter_model::$GREATER_THAN:
                            $select->where->greaterThan('value', $filter_model->value);
                            break;
                        case $filter_model::$LESS_THAN:
                            $select->where->lessThan('value', $filter_model->value);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                $select->group('id');
                $select->limit($limit);

                $adapterPlatform = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql();
                echo $select->getSqlString($adapterPlatform);
            });

    return $rowset;
}
```

This generates the following MySQL statment which is perfectly correct except for one small point, which is extremely important.

```
     SELECT `survey_responses`.*, `question_responses`.`value` AS `value` FROM `survey_responses` INNER JOIN `question_responses` ON `survey_responses`.`id` = `question_responses`.`response_id` WHERE `question_id` = '11' AND `value` > '900' GROUP BY `id` LIMIT 0,100
```

The MySQL statement should produce:

```
     SELECT `survey_responses`.*, `question_responses`.`value` AS `value` FROM `survey_responses` INNER JOIN `question_responses` ON `survey_responses`.`id` = `question_responses`.`response_id` WHERE `question_id` = '11' AND `value` > 900 GROUP BY `id` LIMIT 0,100
```

The difference being the inverted commas round the number 900.

How do I remove these inverted commas from the generated MySQL statement?

n.b this is based on:

```
    $adapterPlatform = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql();
    echo $select->getSqlString($adapterPlatform);
```

Although I do think that this doesn't always generate a correct MySQL string, but its the only thing I have to go by,

Thanks in advance,

Abor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it as an integer:

```
$select->where->greaterThan('value', (int)$filter_model->value);
```

Comment: Are you sure this should work? I have tried it both with (int) and intval(x) and the result is still the same, ie still within the inverted commas.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Typically the issue may have been in the Database, I changed the column type to FLOAT from VARCHAR and the query did indeed work. Without the inverted commas the query worked with VARCHAR, however by making the change to DB it is probably cleaner. Thanks for your help. Abor